# Sidecar: use tap gesture as "click" with a mouse

Tags: macos, mouse, multi-touch, ipados, sidecar

I'm using Sidecar with iPad Pro 11 and MacBook Pro 15 2016.

I noticed, that I could use Apple Pencil to interact with the interface elements on the second screen, e.g. open a new empty tab in Safari.

However, in order to scroll the page, I have to use the "two finger drag" gesture. This is inconvenient and I'd like to use "single finger tap" gesture to interact with elements on the screen, so that it would simulate a mouse click. How can I achieve this result?

The problem is that the switching between having a pencil on the screen or the two fingers is inconvenient and I'd like to either do both actions using gestures or with a pencil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of iPadOS 13.4.1, it is only possible to use your Apple Pencil as a cursor movement technique while using Sidecar. However, I have found it useful to connect my mouse to my Mac and assume that the mouse was connected to my iPad to move the Mac cursor.

You can find more detailed info about this [here](https://www.apple.com/macos/catalina/docs/Sidecar_Tech_Brief_Oct_2019.pdf)!